# Mono HttpWebRequest Post Data Incomplete

Tags: ios, mono, httpwebrequest

I am posting data from the MonoTouch client to my Asp.Net MVC Controller.  However, sometimes I can the following error:

```
   System.ArgumentException: Unterminated string passed in. (49152):
    .....LONG JSON STRING WHICH IS MISSING THE END **" }** and possible other characters.
     at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeString()
       at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
       at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)
       at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
       at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
       at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
       at System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

I was wondering is there any scenario where the HttpWebRequest object in Mono would cut off the request daya, not posting all of it?

The code in Mono is HttpRequest.BeginGetResponse(), which is an async operation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10225888/992406